# Finite groups and manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups

my question is: can we connect finite groups with algebraic manifolds as:

Take for example Togliatti surface $X$ with set of 31 singular points $P$. Then consider action $Aut(X)$ on $P$, then group $G=Aut(X)/Stab(p)$ is finite for all $p\in P$. What properties of $G$ we can prove?

In cases when $Stab(p)$ is not normal subgroup we can take $G=Aut(X)/\cap_{p\in P}Stab(p)$. What finite groups have this representations as manifold?

Comment: By $Aut(X):P$ you mean the action of $Aut(X)$ on $P$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please try to make you question more specific.

Comment: BTW, $Stab(p)$ is not a normal subgroup of $Aut(X)$, so the quotient is not a group.

Comment: Yes, this action

Comment: But maybe in some good cases ($X$ is 'normal') this group is normal subgroup. Anyway $\cap_{p\in P}Stab(p)$ is normal.